# CompactFramework 6.5 hibernate

Tags: windows, mobile, compact-framework

Im developing an app for Compact Framework 6.5 (Windows Mobile).
After starting this app and some time without action (more than 10min) the the system freezes but only while using umts, not wireless lan!

Now I'd like to test whether the devices hibernate is the reason for freezing.

In lower frameworks I could catch `WM_hibernate` and `WM_close` events but in CF 6.5 I cant find the `Microsoft.WindowsCE.Forms` namespace which is needed for the hibernate event.

Does anyone have experience whith this?
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, regarding the namespace, have you added the reference?

[image: Required reference]

Second, WM_HIBERANTE and WM_CLOSE are just constants, so you can add them easily.

```
public const int WM_HIBERNATE = 0x03FF;
public const int WM_CLOSE = 0x0010;
```

Third, just as a point of information for other reader (it's not clear if you're aware of this) WM_HIBERNATE is not related to the device going to "sleep" mode - yes the name is way confusing.  WM_HIBERNATE is actually sent by the OS to close an app when memory resources are low.  Basically your app should respond to it by releasing memory if possible.